# How to customize out of box portlets in liferay 7

Tags: liferay

> I am trying to customize **blog** portlet in **liferay 7.** 
>   
> I wanted to remove hide some part from jsp file.
>   
> How i can do this?

Comment: Could you post your efforts that you have done so far?

Comment: Thanks for replied.  I have create new theme using eclipse. I have got theme structured in that like: demo-theme -> src -> main -> in this directory has two folder resources and webapp ,  Inside Resources folder has sitemap.json and webapps under has css -> _custom.scss.

Comment: i wanted to do some changes into portal_normal.vm.  Is it possible in liferay 7? if yes, then how i will achieve?

Answer (score 0):

to change some part of core jsp you should use jsp hook. In Liferay 7 you need a osgi fragment module

- symbolic name and version in the OSGi header Fragment-Host declaration.
- provide a complete copy of the original JSP with any modifications you need to make.

check: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-core-jsps for more details